# Tuning solr ConcurrentMergeScheduler

Tags: solr

I'm running solr on a server with two SSD disks. 
The disk appears to be rotational, I guess because hardware raid mirroring is configured

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
1
```

After reading  [Taking Solr to Production](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/taking-solr-to-production.html#dynamic-defaults-for-concurrentmergescheduler) I want to check how ConcurrentMergeScheduler is running.

1) solr autodetect disks as rotational (4 cores here)

```
curl -s localhost:8983/solr/admin/metrics |grep CORE.fs.spins
      "CORE.fs.spins":true,
      "CORE.fs.spins":true,
      "CORE.fs.spins":true,
      "CORE.fs.spins":true,
```

2) I've added `lucene.cms.override_spins=true` to `SOLR_OPTS` (and restarted)

3) solr still detects `"CORE.fs.spins":true` and `"lucene.cms.override_spins":"true"`

Am I missing something? Are they other tweaks to improve ConcurrentMergeScheduler? Should I notice relevant speed improvement?

Comment: Can you confirm which version of Solr you are using? Can you also confirm where you set SOLR_OPTS? Thanks!

Comment: solr 7.6.0 - i have put SOLR_OPTS in `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` and i'm using the solr init.d script

Comment: If you get a process list (e.g. "ps -ef") can you see the option set correctly in the command line arguments?

Comment: sure, i can from the dashboard too https://i.imgur.com/uB50dAz.png given this, how i can check the values of ConcurrentMergeScheduler?

Comment: It looks like you have set it correctly. But according to this code https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java#L417 that setting is only obeyed if maxThreadCount=-1 - by any chance are you overriding maxThreadCount?

Comment: no, i'm not overridding `maxThreadCount` setting. how i can check this setting? i cannot find it exposed in metrics api

Comment: Hmmm sorry I can't be of more help - I'm at the limit of my knowledge. May I suggest you try the Solr/Lucene mailing list http://lucene.apache.org/solr/community.html#mailing-lists-irc I hope you find an answer!

Comment: Wouldn't you want `lucene.cms.override_spins=false` (false not true!) to tell it that it is not a spinning drive?